# generating querying result for row() in codeigniter:

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newbie in codeigniter. If I have a model like this :

```
public function get_data_for_reminder($id) {
    $this->db->select('nama_user, keluhan, email, addresed_to');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('id_request' => $id));
    return $query->row();
}
```

And I try to accessed it from may controller :

```
public function reminderIT() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = $this->model_request->get_data_for_reminder($id);
```

How to Generating Query Results, thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
I am new in CI, my question is : let's say I want to get the 'nama_user' into an a variable like this :

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
        $name = $d['nama_user'];

    }

    echo json_encode($name);
```

I use firebug, it gives me null. I think my foreach is in a problem

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line?

Comment: Wahat is your question? Do you get errors or no data?

Comment: Look at answer from @saty .. `$query->row();` returns an object, if you would like to return an array from your query, use `$query->row_array();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller File with your query code**

```
public function reminderIT() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = $this->model_request->get_data_for_reminder($id); 
    //Generating Query Results like this because you use $query->row();
   $data->nama_user;
   $data->keluhan;
   $data->email;
   $data->addresed_to; 
   $info_json = array("nama_user" => $data->nama_user, "keluhan" => $data->keluhan, "email" =>  $data->email, "addresed_to" =>  $data->addresed_to);

    echo json_encode($info_json);
}
```

**MODEL.PHP**

```
public function get_data_for_reminder($id) {
    $this->db->select('nama_user, keluhan, email, addresed_to');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('id_request' => $id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

//Generating Query Results if  use $query->row_array(); in model file

**Controller.php**

```
function reminderIT() {

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = $this->model_request->get_data_for_reminder($id);
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
    $myArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to return an array from your model call you can use [`result_array()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) as

```
public function get_data_for_reminder($id) {
    $this->db->select('nama_user, keluhan, email, addresed_to');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('id_request' => $id));
    return $query->result_array();//<---- This'll always return you set of an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You fetched data for selected id it means you get a single row, if you want to get "nama_user" then in your controller:

```
public function reminderIT() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = $this->model_request->get_data_for_reminder($id); 
    $name = $data->nama_user;
    echo json_encode($name);
}
```